# How to add Header and Footer in dynamic pdf using iTextLibrary?

Tags: android, header, pdf-generation, itext, footer

I have created a **PDF** file **dynamically** using **iText** Library, Now I want to add **Header** and **Footer** in PDF's pages, for this one I have added given code:

```
document.addHeader("My Header Title", "My Header Details");
```

But in my PDF's pages this header couldn't set. What is issue that I don't know, If you have any idea related to it,please share your thoughts.

Comment: While you may have experienced that issue on an android device, your question contains nothing specific to android, neither does the accepted answer. Thus, there is no need for the [tag:android] tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case you use a current iText version (i.e. 5.4.x as of now) have a look at the sample [MovieHistory2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103) from [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) which shows how to add headers (different ones for odd and even pages) to a PDF while creating it.

Most essential is a `PdfPageEventHelper` implementation

```
/** Inner class to add a header and a footer. */
class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    /** Alternating phrase for the header. */
    Phrase[] header = new Phrase[2];
    /** Current page number (will be reset for every chapter). */
    int pagenumber;

    /**
     * Initialize one of the headers.
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onOpenDocument(
     *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
     */
    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        header[0] = new Phrase("Movie history");
    }

    /**
     * Initialize one of the headers, based on the chapter title;
     * reset the page number.
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onChapter(
     *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document, float,
     *      com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph)
     */
    public void onChapter(PdfWriter writer, Document document,
            float paragraphPosition, Paragraph title) {
        header[1] = new Phrase(title.getContent());
        pagenumber = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Increase the page number.
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onStartPage(
     *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
     */
    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        pagenumber++;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the header and the footer.
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(
     *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
     */
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
        switch(writer.getPageNumber() % 2) {
        case 0:
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header[0],
                    rect.getRight(), rect.getTop(), 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_LEFT, header[1],
                    rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop(), 0);
            break;
        }
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("page %d", pagenumber)),
                (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
    }
}
```

which is registered like this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter();
writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments, a simpler variant of the `onEndPage` method with a static header instead of the alternating one:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("My static header text"),
        rect.getRight(), rect.getTop(), 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("page %d", pagenumber)),
        (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i added page no as a page footer. now i want to add header in my page. If u have idea, than pls help me. Thanks...

Comment: The iText sample code in my answer already shows how to set both headers and footers. It shows in turns a hard coded document title (`"Movie history"`) and the current chapter title. If you don't use `Chapter` in your document, you may want to boil down that `switch` statement to a single `ColumnText.showTextAligned.`

Comment: I just edited the answer to also contain a simpler implementation of `onEndPage` with a static header instead of the alternating one. The code was there before, too, it merely was more flexible

Comment: I have added your updated code and finally i got Header. Thanks for you communication.....Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to change header and footer for every page

Comment: @mekala In the sample above the footer *is changed for every page*.

Comment: i tried like this but text in the header is merge @mkl                     just luk at here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029364/how-to-change-header-for-every-pdf-page-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Please first refer to the accepted answer of this question.

That answer is very helpful (and It helped me too).

Just in case you are programming in C#, here is the SAME accepted answer but in C# version

```
/// <summary>
/// Inner class to add a header and a footer.
/// </summary>
internal class HeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    private Phrase[] header = new Phrase[2];
    private int pageNumber;

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        header[0] = new Phrase("Smares in Header");
    }

    public override void OnChapter(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, Paragraph title)
    {
        header[1] = new Phrase(title.Content);
        pageNumber = 1;
    }

    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        pageNumber++;
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        Rectangle rect = writer.GetBoxSize("art");
        switch (writer.PageNumber % 2)
        {
            case 0:
                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent,
                        Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header[0],
                        rect.Right, rect.Top, 0);
                break;
            case 1:
                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent,
                        Element.ALIGN_LEFT, header[1],
                        rect.Left, rect.Top, 0);
                break;
        }

        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent,
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.Format("page {0}", pageNumber)),
                (rect.Left + rect.Right) / 2, rect.Bottom - 18, 0);
    }
}
```

and the registration of the event will be :

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, -30, -30, 45, 45))
    {
        using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
        {
             HeaderFooter ev = new HeaderFooter();
             writer.SetBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));
             writer.PageEvent = ev;

             // continue your code here 
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is just a conversion of the accepted answer from java to C#.
but you can customize this according to your needs, as I did with it.

Further Reading: https://www.coderanch.com/wiki/660110/iText-OpenPDF

Answer (score -3):

You can add like that

```
HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Add Header Part Here"), false);  
HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Add Footer Here"), new Phrase("."));  

document.setHeader(header);  
document.setFooter(footer);
```