# How to add Header and footer to my PDF using Itext in java

Tags: java, itext

I want to add a header image and page numbers as footer to my PDF file. How can I add header and footer to my PDF file using Itext?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Header;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Demo {
/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Demo().createPDF();
}
public void createPDF(){
Document document = new Document (PageSize.A4);
try {
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/mnavya/Desktop/AddImage.pdf"));
document.open ();
document.addCreator("Binod by Demo.java");
document.addAuthor("Binod Suman");
document.addTitle("First PDF By Binod");
Image image = Image.getInstance("https://snaplogic-h.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/partner/logo/24/stratappa.jpg?u=1382443264");
image.scaleAbsolute(50,50);
document.add(image);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(
        " Factors",new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 25));
document.add(paragraph);
document.add(Chunk.SPACETABBING);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
float[] columnWidths = new float[] { 7, 20, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 3 };
table.setWidths(columnWidths);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setColspan(8);
cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell(" ");
table.addCell(" ");
table.addCell("");
table.addCell("");
table.addCell("%");
table.addCell("");
table.addCell(" ");
table.addCell(" ");
document.add(table);
document.close ();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("******** PDF Created ***************");
}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214756/how-to-add-header-and-footer-in-dynamic-pdf-using-itextlibrary/17217346#17217346) to [How to add Header and Footer in dynamic pdf using iTextLibrary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214756/how-to-add-header-and-footer-in-dynamic-pdf-using-itextlibrary).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Footer Header utils:**

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class HeaderFooterPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Top Left"), 30, 800, 0);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Top Right"), 550, 800, 0);
    }

    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("http://www.xxxx-your_example.com/"), 110, 30, 0);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("page " + document.getPageNumber()), 550, 30, 0);
    }

}
```

**Use HeaderFooterPageEvent:**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 50, 25);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
HeaderFooterPageEvent event = new HeaderFooterPageEvent();
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

**EDIT (add image sample):**

```
public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    String img = APPLICATION_SERVER_ROOT_PATH + File.separator + "assets" + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "logo-tp-white.png";
    Image image;
    try {
        image = Image.getInstance(img);
        image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(20, 790);
        image.scalePercent(7.5f, 7.5f);
        writer.getDirectContent().addImage(image, true);
    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        log.error("L'image logo-tp-50x50.png a provoqué une erreur.", e);
    }

    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(""), 30, 800, 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(Constants.GLOBAL_HOST + " pour réussir votre prochain concours."), 400, 800, 0);
}
```

Comment: Any way to add images on header/footer

Comment: Does this also work for `PDFAWriter` or is there any change required? I am not able to use this for PDF/A-2

Comment: @Sumit, I think so because `PdfAWriter` extends `PdfWriter` (http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAWriter.html)

Comment: @sgrillon I am getting the exception related to font not being embedded in `new Phrase()`, is there any method to add a `paragraph` or set `font` of phrase as an embedded font?

Answer (score 4):

```
 HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter();
  writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));
  writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

[document itxt](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103)

ejemplo
[example of PDF](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/movie_history2.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at [the official iText documentation](http://itextpdf.com/learn) before posting a question on StackOverflow. More specifically: check the examples for the keyword [header / footer](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=221).

You'll find the [MovieCountries1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) example that creates a [PDF with a header that has page numbers](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/movie_countries1.pdf) Page 1 / 39, Page 2 / 39, etc.

Use that example as inspiration. If you don't need a *Page X of Y* header (or footer). You can use a more simple example, such as the one in the answer to [How to add Header and Footer in dynamic pdf using iTextLibrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214756/how-to-add-header-and-footer-in-dynamic-pdf-using-itextlibrary) (which was also inspired by one of the examples of my book).

Comment: Example is appreciated, but remember linkrot and why [link only answers aren't really good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/273645).

Answer (score 2):

I am using iText2.
Although PdfPageEventHelper can solve it, HeaderFooter seems more easier.
Make sure add HeaderFooter before document.open(), otherwise first page will not display it.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("- "), new Phrase(" -"));
footer.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
footer.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
document.setFooter(footer);
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help you for adding header and footer using `itext` :

```
public class PageNumber  extends PdfPageEventHelper{
private PdfTemplate t;
private Image total;

public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    t = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 16);
    try {
        total = Image.getInstance(t);
        total.setRole(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    addHeader(writer);
    addFooter(writer);
}

private void addHeader(PdfWriter writer){
    PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(1);
    try {
        // set defaults
        header.setWidths(new int[]{100});
        header.setTotalWidth(525);
        header.setLockedWidth(true);
        header.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(65);
        header.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        header.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

        // add image
        Image logo = Image.getInstance(PageNumber.class.getResource("/sample.png"));
        header.addCell(logo);


        // write content
        header.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 823, writer.getDirectContent());
    } catch(DocumentException de) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    }
}


private void addFooter(PdfWriter writer){
    PdfPTable footer = new PdfPTable(1);
    try {

        footer.setWidths(new int[]{100});
        footer.setTotalWidth(527);
        footer.setLockedWidth(false);
        footer.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(40);
        footer.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
        footer.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

        // add current page count
        footer.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        footer.addCell(new Phrase(String.format( writer.getPageNumber()+ " | Page") , new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD)));

        // write page
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
        footer.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 50, canvas);
        canvas.endMarkedContentSequence();
    } catch(DocumentException de) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    }
}

public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    int totalLength = String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber()).length();
    int totalWidth = totalLength * 5;
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(t, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber()),new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12)),
            totalWidth, 6, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer essentially uses the same technique as the earlier, accepted answer. In which way does your answer exceed that answer?

Comment: yeah your right., but i thought that it will also help me that any new suggestion regarding this .

Answer (score 0):

```
HeaderFooter header =new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(resources.getMessage("your header")),false);
                header.setAlignment(HeaderFooter.ALIGN_CENTER);
                header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                document.setHeader(header);
                document.open();
```