# how to change header for every pdf page in android

Tags: java, android, itext

I created pdf page using itext in android application,need to add header and footer for pdf page and need to change header in every page.

i did like for adding header and footer

public class HeaderAddFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

```
private Phrase footer;
private Phrase header;
private String patientName;
private String patientID;
Font headerFont = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);
Font footerFont = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);
Font TitleFont = new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 14, Font.NORMAL);

/*
 * constructor
 */
public HeaderAddFooter(String name,String id) {
    super();

    header = new Phrase("***** Header *****");
    footer = new Phrase("**** Footer ****");
    patientName=name;
    patientID=id;
}


@Override
public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

    super.onStartPage(writer, document);


}

@Override
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   // Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();



  ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("welcome",headerFont), 
            document.leftMargin()-1, document.top()+10, 0);

    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("Name",headerFont), 
            document.right(), document.top()+15, 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("Designation",headerFont), 
            document.right(), document.top()+1, 0);


    /*
     * Foooter
     */

    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, new Phrase("Page:"+String.format(" %d ", 
            writer.getPageNumber()),footerFont), 
            document.right() - 280 , document.bottom() - 10, 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, new Phrase(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()),footerFont), 

            document.right() - 350 , document.bottom() - 25, 0);


}
```

}

now when add new values to header it showing like merge text both previous text and new header text. how can i change header dynamically for every page

Comment: *when add new values to header it showing like merge text both previous text and new header text* - how do you add new values? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: for first page it showing properly then for second page need to send again values at the time new header showing on the previous header

Comment: **How do you add new values? I don't see it in your code.** You said that your way of doing it mixes former and current header somehow. With the code you show that cannot be reproduced. Thus, we cannot tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: sending values to constructor for each page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asked how he *adds new values to header,* the OP clarified in a comment that he does so by

> sending values to constructor for each page

This seems to indicate that he every once in a while creates a new `HeaderAddFooter` instance and forwards it to the `PdfWriter` method `setPageEvent`.

Unfortunately the OP was not able or willing to provide more code. Thus, let's assume his code looks like this

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, ...);
document.open();

for (int page = ...)
{
    String nameForPage = ...
    String idForPage = ...
    writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderAddFooter(nameForPage, idForPage));

    ... add content for page ...
    document.newPage();
}

document.close();
```

This, unfortunately, does not work as expected because `PdfWriter.setPageEvent` is a bit misnamed (and also mis-documented in the Javadocs): It is not a true setter but instead more like an adder:

```
public void setPageEvent(final PdfPageEvent event) {
    if (event == null) this.pageEvent = null;
    else if (this.pageEvent == null) this.pageEvent = event;
    else if (this.pageEvent instanceof PdfPageEventForwarder) ((PdfPageEventForwarder)this.pageEvent).addPageEvent(event);
    else {
        PdfPageEventForwarder forward = new PdfPageEventForwarder();
        forward.addPageEvent(this.pageEvent);
        forward.addPageEvent(event);
        this.pageEvent = forward;
    }
}
```

Thus, the OP's *assumed* code does **not replace** the former page event listener by a new one but insteads **adds** to it.

There are two ways to fix this:

- Either set only one `HeaderAddFooter` instance initially outside the loop and change the contents of its members inside the loop:

  ```
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, ...);
  document.open();
  HeaderAddFooter headerAddFooter = new HeaderAddFooter("", "");
  writer.setPageEvent(headerAddFooter);

  for (int page = ...)
  {
      String nameForPage = ...
      String idForPage = ...
      headerAddFooter.patientName = nameForPage;
      headerAddFooter.patientID = idForPage;

      ... add content for page ...
      document.newPage();
  }

  document.close();
  ```

  This most likely will require making those `HeaderAddFooter` member variables more visible. Alternatively setter methods may be added for them.
- Or make use of the special treatment of `null` in `PdfWriter.setPageEvent`:

  ```
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, ...);
  document.open();

  for (int page = ...)
  {
      String nameForPage = ...
      String idForPage = ...
      writer.setPageEvent(null);
      writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderAddFooter(nameForPage, idForPage));

      ... add content for page ...
      document.newPage();
  }

  document.close();
  ```

The first alternative (with the use of setter methods for cleaner code) is the more common variant.

Comment: nice work @mkl but pdf page is employee details it may contain 1 or 2 or 3. can it possible change header using page

Comment: Please explain, I don't see a problem. If you need a more flexible header structure, simply program some flexibility into onPageEnd.